# Google Sheets: Copying cells and sorting it in another tab

Tags: javascript, java, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have a big document list ("MDR") from multiple projects and im trying to sort them as in progress/ done. It looks somethink like this:

| Project | Document | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Doc11 | Done |
| 1 | Doc12 | In progress |
| 1 | Doc13 | Done |
| 2 | Doc21 | In progress |
| 2 | Doc22 | Done |
| 2 | Doc23 | In progress |

I select the status from a data validation dropdown list.

And i want a second tab ("GPO") to filter this first MDR tab for projects that are In progress, so it would be like this:

| Project | Document | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Doc12 | In progress |
| 2 | Doc21 | In progress |
| 2 | Doc23 | In progress |

Plus, i would like in case i got a revision on Doc13 to it be added on the second tab in his place:

| Project | Document | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Doc12 | In progress |
| 1 | Doc13 | In progress |
| 2 | Doc21 | In progress |
| 2 | Doc23 | In progress |

I tried using query and filter, but it doesnt work since i also need to assign information in the "GPO" tab, then information would get misplaced when adding/deleting rows.

Also tried making a macro for it, but got no luck, wasn't able to set it to trigger when i change the status of the project, neither i found a way to sort it in the right row.

I can't add filters in the MDR tab and write there since it's also used for other activities.

Can it be done via macros?

Or it would be easier with scripts? If so, what i should look into to find my answer?

I appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 1):

```
function myfunc101() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  sh2.clearContents();
  const sh3 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  sh3.clearContents();
  const [hA,...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let inProg = vs.map(r=>{if(r[2]=='In progress'){return r}}).filter(e=>e);
  let done = vs.map(r=>{if(r[2]=='Done'){return r}}).filter(e=>e);
  inProg.unshift(hA);//add headers
  sh2.getRange(1,1,inProg.length,inProg[0].length).setValues(inProg);
  done.unshift(hA);//add headers
  sh3.getRange(1,1,done.length,done[0].length).setValues(done);
}
```

Sheet 1:

| Project | Document | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Doc11 | Done |
| 1 | Doc12 | In progress |
| 1 | Doc13 | Done |
| 2 | Doc21 | In progress |
| 2 | Doc22 | Done |
| 2 | Doc23 | In progress |

Sheet 2:

| Project | Document | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Doc12 | In progress |
| 2 | Doc21 | In progress |
| 2 | Doc23 | In progress |

Sheet 3:

| Project | Document | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Doc11 | Done |
| 1 | Doc13 | Done |
| 2 | Doc22 | Done |

Comment: With this script i get the same problem as with query/filter functions.

On the second sheet i need to place information on the side of status (ex: the amount of hours to work on each document), and this has to go on this sheet, can't be on the first one, then when i add new projects or remove them that information gets deleted by:

sh2.clearContents();

If i delete the clearContents, what i had written gets misplaced when adding/ deleting projects.

Maybe this can be done by inserting/deleting the rows instead of always rewriting everything?

Comment: I don't have access to any of that data.  It was not in the original question.  Please provide images of the appropriate sheets and explain the requirements.  Do not bother providing me with links to spreadsheets because I will not follow them.

Comment: The first [image](https://imgur.com/a/Zfir2Bd) is the Sheet2 in your answer, the script got the columns from A to R, just like i wanted. The columns X to AB i need to input it manually. See how i have highlighted the 4th row, project 3214, and added hours of work per day.
On the second image, still on Sheet2, i added a new project, 1122, and it's on top of the 3214, the script worked for this, but now the 1122 is the 4th row and have the allocated hours to it instead of the project 3214. That's what i meant on my original post about using query and my information being misplaced.

Comment: If the additional data that you wish to be on  Sheet2 is not on Sheet1 then where does it come from.

Comment: I'll input it manually depending on the project progress. Sheet2 will be updated daily with different projects and the amount of hours needed in these projects.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you want.  Your posed a problem that wasn't your real problem.  Perhaps you should pose another problem that represents your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could achieve that using a pivot table,
As you want an auto refreshing filtered table external to your data one.
If you're unfamiliar with pivot tables, read here:
[https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#:~:text=Pivot%20table.,%2C%22%20choose%20a%20pivot%20table](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#:%7E:text=Pivot%20table.,%2C%22%20choose%20a%20pivot%20table)
or here:
https://coefficient.io/guide-to-using-pivot-tables-in-google-sheets?ref=quuu